# Rooms Volume Computations - Strange behavior & What is the most accurate way to get the Rooms Solids?

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

An interesting behavior I found, attempting to get the most accurate Rooms volume solids, was that: when turning on the Room Volumes computations it looks like Revit will only get you the bounding shape of the room at the "Unbounded Room Height".. !!

Here is the Room with Unbounded Height being 15m + Volume Computations Turned ON:

[15 m unbound height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00DTE.png)

...here is the unbound height with 6m + Volume Computations Turned ON:

[6 m unbound height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjHnG.png)

...here is the unbound height with 3m + Volume Computations Turned ON:

[3 m unbound height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWwiu.png)

Getting the Room's Solid:

```
private static Solid _FirstSolid (Element elem)
{
    Options op = new Options();
    Solid roomSolid = (elem.get_Geometry(op) as GeometryElement).FirstOrDefault() as Solid;
    return roomSolid;   
}
```

Baking with DirectShapes:

```
using (Transaction t = new Transaction(doc,"bake Room Geometry"))
{
    t.Start();
    DirectShape ds = DirectShape.CreateElement(doc,new ElementId(BuiltInCategory.OST_GenericModel));
    ds.SetShape((new List<GeometryObject> {transSolid as GeometryObject}));
    t.Commit();
    t.Dispose();
}
```

Not sure if this is the intended behavior of the Volume Computations! But it is also changing the computed Volume value when we change the unbounded heights!

What is the best way anyone came across to get the most accurate Room's Volume Solids? is the Energy Analysis API a more reliable way of going around this? any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely take a look at the [Room.GetClosedShell method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/58410893-1269-98e3-7a07-e5dacafbc9fe.htm), cf. my [Room Closed Shell DirectShape for Forge Viewer](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/06/improved-room-closed-shell-directshape-for-forge-viewer.html#4), also [RoomVolumeDirectShape on GitHub](https://github.com/jeremytammik/RoomVolumeDirectShape).

If you wish to use the energy analysis API, please be aware that the [EnergyAnalysisDetailModelOptions settings](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/cc97d633-487a-193a-6adf-396d86a3eb33.htm)   affect the computations, cf. [Two Different Energy Model Types](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/07/self-organising-architecture-and-voxel-based-energy-analysis.html#6).

Comment: Many Thanks Jeremy, will dig deeper into your links and keep you posted.. much appreciated. @JeremyTammik